# Openwhisk alternative to IBM?

Tags: serverless, ibm-cloud, openwhisk

IBM is deprecating Cloud Functions, its Openwhisk Functions as a service offering.

Is there anybody else proposing a similar offering?

I know I could use a generic hosting service and install Openwhisk there but I am looking for a drop-in replacement of IBM cloud functions, where autoscaling and downscaling is managed etc

I know I could migrate to other Functions as a Service offering, not using Openwhisk, but I am looking for a solution which would not require adapting code, just changing the target host.

Does anything of the sort exist?